# jQuery slider on divs

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm trying to get jQuery slider to work with my divs instead of images...
Is there a way to do this with slider controls?
I have slider controls built as li lists.
any suggestions guys?

Below is what I have:

```
<div class="slide-show" id="slide-show">
                <div class="slide-1" id="slide-1">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Connect with fellow food lovers</h1>
                        <p>Share your passion for food with friends, and form an exclusive society with a direct connection to the finest restaurants and cafes.</p>
                        <a href="#"><img src="img/home/home-join-now.png" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide-2" id="slide-2">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Connect with fellow food lovers</h1>
                        <p>Share your passion for food with friends, and form an exclusive society with a direct connection to the finest restaurants and cafes.</p>
                        <a href="#"><img src="img/home/home-join-now.png" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide-3" id="slide-3">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Connect with fellow food lovers</h1>
                        <p>Share your passion for food with friends, and form an exclusive society with a direct connection to the finest restaurants and cafes.</p>
                        <a href="#"><img src="img/home/home-join-now.png" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-control">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">1</a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">2</a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: [Some code please](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like [Content Carousel](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/16/circular-content-carousel/) ????

Comment: Yea I want something like that but with auto sliding effect and clickable slidercontrol for each content not just arrows with previous and next...

Comment: Is that API for a different slider? It looks like that is for BxSlider, not Content Carousel.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what happened with the link. Recently I found a plugin called caroufredsel. It has a step by step mecahnism to generate required options.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found this Caroufredsel plugin. Its a carousel plugin with fred in the middle!!. I am using it in my production code. Take a look it might be helpful. It also has a 'robot' which helps us configure our carousel. Hope this will be helpful.
http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/